# Panel Data to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, panel-data

I have a dataframe (a small snippet is shown below)

[image: Dataframe layout]

I believe the data is laid out in a panel data format where each ticker has a number of historical data associated with it (only 'GOOG' is shown in the image).

I would like to know if there is a simple way to convert the dataframe into a dictionary such that:

```
key = ticker
value = dataframe of all historical data associated with that ticker.
```

I was thinking to do a simple groupby on tickers before and carry on from there.

Edit:
ideally I would like a method that is mostly scalable since the original dataframe is very large.

Comment: Assuming your DataFrame is in a variable `df`, this can probably be done with `df.set_index('Ticker').to_dict(orient='index')`. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: `{t: df[df['Ticker'] == t] for t in df['Ticker'].unique()}`

Comment: Do you think these methods would be suitable for large dataframes? I